# Conditional Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have a file in format:

```
011110659
            A101    000001    $.45          
031100762
            1030    000001    $.45          
071000288
            1040    000003   $1.35          
            1040    000001    $.45          
103100195
            1030    000001  $33.45          
            J5BU    000001    $.45
```

And I would like to use regular expression to make it look like

```
011110659   A101    000001    $.45
031100762   1030    000001    $.45
071000288   1040    000003   $1.35
071000288   1040    000001    $.45
103100195   1030    000001  $33.45
103100195   J5BU    000001    $.45
```

What I am looking to do is to copy the text which have only one string in the whole line and append it in front of the subsequent lines which have more than 1 string already.

I can do this with a programming script but is there a way to do this with regular expression?

Comment: why do you want to do this with a regular expression?

Comment: Perhaps two regular expressions, the first one finding lines beginning with spaces that copies in the 9-digit number above, then another to remove the lines containing only the 9-digit numbers.

Comment: What do you mean "with regular expression"? What program/tool/language?

Comment: Regular expressions are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Comment: Hello Andy: I would like to do this using notepad++

Answer (score 0):

### No.

About the closest you can get is replacing `((?<=\n|^)\d+)\s+\r?\n` with `$1`. Demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/qD5rJ6

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not as concise as you were hoping for, but this works. Regex is *important* to this, but not *critical*.

Top and setup:

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
   import  java.util.ArrayList;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
   <P>{@code java FormatDataLinesWithRegexXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class FormatDataLinesWithRegexXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      String sLS = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\\n");
      StringBuilder sdInput = new StringBuilder().
         append("011110659                                                            ").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("                          A101            000001                 $.45").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("031100762                                                            ").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("                          1030            000001                 $.45").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("071000288                                                            ").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("                          1040            000003                $1.35").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("                          1040            000001                 $.45").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("103100195                                                            ").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("                          1030            000001               $33.45").append(sLS).
         append("                                                                     ").append(sLS).
         append("                          J5BU            000001                 $.45").append(sLS);
```

Main logic:

```
      //config
         int iCOL1LEN = 9;
         String sRE234 = "" +
            "(\\w{4})[\\t ]+" +               //Column 2
            "(\\d{6})[\\t ]+" +               //Column 3
            "\\$(\\d*\\.*\\d+)$";             //Column 4
      Pattern p234 = Pattern.compile(sRE234);

      ArrayList<String> alLines = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sdInput.toString().split(sLS)));
      ArrayList<DataLine> aldl = new ArrayList<DataLine>();

      System.out.println("read...START");
      DataLine dlCurr = null;
      int iLn = -1;

      while(alLines.size() > 0)  {
         iLn++;              //1st iteration: was -1, now 0

         String sLine = alLines.remove(0).trim();
         if(sLine.length() == 0)  {
            continue;

         }  else if(sLine.length() == iCOL1LEN)  {
            if(dlCurr != null)  {
               throw  new IllegalStateException("[line " + iLn + "]: Found two column-1s in a row.");
            }
            dlCurr = new DataLine(sLine);
            System.out.print("1");

         }  else if(p234.matcher(sLine).matches())  {
            if(dlCurr == null)  {
               //Current 234-columns have no corresponding column-1.
               //Use previous.
               dlCurr = new DataLine(aldl.get(aldl.size() - 1).sCol1);
               System.out.print("1");
            }
            dlCurr.set234(sLine);
            aldl.add(dlCurr);
            System.out.println("234");
            dlCurr = null;
         }
      }
      System.out.println("read...END");

      System.out.println("Output:");

      for(DataLine dl : aldl)  {
         System.out.println(dl.sCol1 + "        " + dl.sCol2 + "        " + dl.sCol3 + "        " + dl.sCol4);
      }
   }
}
```

A simple data-holder class:

```
class DataLine  {
   public String sCol1 = null;
   public String sCol2 = null;
   public String sCol3 = null;
   public String sCol4 = null;
   public DataLine(String s_col1)  {
      sCol1 = s_col1;
   }
   public void set234(String s_234)  {
      String[] as = s_234.split("[\t ]+");
      sCol2 = as[0];
      sCol3 = as[1];
      sCol4 = as[2];
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java FormatDataLinesWithRegexXmpl
read...START
1234
1234
1234
1234
1234
1234
read...END
Output:
011110659        A101        000001        $.45
031100762        1030        000001        $.45
071000288        1040        000003        $1.35
071000288        1040        000001        $.45
103100195        1030        000001        $33.45
103100195        J5BU        000001        $.45
```